# The entity type ' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos utilizando Code first en Entity Framework Core con el siguiente modelo:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace dotnet_api.Logic.DTO
{
    public class DepartmentDTO
    {
        [Key]
        private Guid dep_id {get; set;}
        private string dep_name {get; set;}
        private string dep_description {get; set;}
        private List<OfficeDTO> offices {get; set;}
        private List<EmployeeDTO> employees {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
The entity type 'DepartmentDTO' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Mi data context luce de la siguiente manera:

```
namespace dotnet_api.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options){}
        public DbSet<PersonDTO> Persons {get; set;}
        public DbSet<EmployeeDTO> Employees  {get; set;}
        public DbSet<ClientDTO> Clients {get; set;}
        public DbSet<BuildingDTO> Buildings {get; set;}
        public DbSet<LocationDTO> Locations {get; set;}
        public DbSet<OfficeDTO> Offices {get; set;}
        public DbSet<DepartmentDTO> Departments {get; set;}
        public DbSet<PositionDTO> Positions {get; set;}
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDTO>().ToTable(t => {
                t.HasCheckConstraint(
                "per_gender_chk",
                "per_gender = 'male' or per_gender = 'female' or per_gender = 'other'"
                );
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<LocationDTO>().ToTable(t => {
                t.HasCheckConstraint(
                "loc_type_chk",
                "loc_type = 'municipio' or loc_type = 'ciudad' or loc_type = 'estado' or loc_type = 'pais'"
                );
            });
        }

    }
}
```

No entiendo por qué me sale ese error si con el Data Annotations estoy declarando que la variable dep_id en la entidad DepartmentDTO tiene la etiqueta [Key]

Comment: Pon el código de esta tabla LocationDTO

Comment: @Yussef disculpa, ya modifiqué la pregunta, el error no era en locationDTO, sino en DepartmentDTO.

Comment: Tienes la propiedades en private, cambialas a public

Comment: Y si me permites hacer un par de recomendaciones. Hay un patrón DTO, el cual a mi humilde opinión no aplica en asp.mvc (pero hay gente que insiste en usarlo). Pero lo tuyo es raro, porque nombras tus clases como DTO, y las ocupas directamente para guardar en la BD. También te recomiendo leer https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions para que veas como debes nombrar las propiedades

Comment: @Yussef muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo todo esto, es algo nuevo para mi

Comment: Ojo al dato: un DTO != una entidad.